# CORS Error accessing Lambda function from S3-hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cors

This is a duplicate question, in the sense that it is about an issue I've read about in plenty of other stackoverflow posts already. However, none of the solutions I found seem to work for my particular configuration, which is why I wanted to ask again with my own details.

I have set up an S3 bucket, containing my html/javascript for my website. I made this bucket open for all to see, and added the following CORS policies on it:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "OPTIONS"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
```

The core of my service's functionality, however, lies in a Lambda function (which internally communicates with DynamoDB). To access this Lambda function from my S3-hosted website, I also added an API gateway.

Firstly, I added the following in my Lambda request handling:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
};
```

The headers are later returned as part of the request result.

My API Gateway is quite simple, and is just composed of one single URL, configured as follows:

[image: pic1]

Furthermore, I enabled CORS on this API Gateway like so:

[image: pic2]

When I click on "Stages", some other request methods appear as well, but I don't think they are enabled/matter:

[image]

So, basically, I have enabled CORS on 3 different points: On my S3 bucket, in my Lambda code, and on the API Gateway. Yet, when I try to access my Lambda function by sending a POST-Request to my API Gateway from the website on my bucket, I get the following error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://----.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/default/----' from origin 'http://------.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

And, well, I simply don't know how to continue. I've read the CORS Docs of AWS, and I've scrolled Stackoverflow extensively, yet I don't seem to be able to reproduce a working environment myself...

Comment: I'd read, or re-read, the API Gateway [CORS troubleshooting guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/) and [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

Comment: @jarmod I did, and I still can't figure it out. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or am just dumb, but I guess that's why I created this post, because I ust can't figure out what isn't working

Comment: have you deployed the Stage?

Comment: Where are you seeing the cors error? In the developer console? You can also get a cors error if your function bugs out before returning an http response - put a try/catch block around your code and then change the response code to 500 in the catch, see if that changes your error.

Answer (score 1):

try sending the CORS header as a response from your lambda function.
It could be possible reason why you're getting this error.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

[Refer here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)